# angularjs - Live display tabs when localstorage has a value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

i'm trying to hide some tabs and enable it only when the username `localstorage` variable username contains a value. i'm able to hide correctly but when the localstorage get a value the tabs doesn't display

```
<ion-tabs  ng-controller="tabs_ctrl" class="tabs-icon-top  tabs-positive">


  <ion-tab ng-if ="username==null" title="Sign In" icon="ion-log-in" href="#/tab/signin">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-signin"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>


  <ion-tab ng-if ="username==null" title="Create Account" icon="ion-person">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-create_account"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>



  <ion-tab ng-if ="username!=null" title="My Account" icon="ion-person" href="#/tab/account">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-user_account"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>


  <ion-tab ng-if ="username!=null" title="Billing" icon="ion-ios-paper" href="#/tab/billing">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-billing"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

tabs controller

```
.controller('tabs_ctrl',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.username = localStorage.getItem("username");
             }])
```

this is my login controller and when the user login is correct i set the username localstorage value but the view doesn't get updated to display the tabs which are suppose to who when user logs in

```
.controller('login_ctrl',['$scope','$http','$timeout','$ionicModal','$ionicLoading','$ionicPopup','$location','$cordovaToast','$location',function($scope,$http,$timeout,$ionicModal,$ionicLoading,$ionicPopup,$location,$cordovaToast,$location){

    $scope.mainlogin= function(){
    $ionicLoading.show({template: '<p>Please Wait...</p><ion-spinner></ion-spinner>'});
        event.preventDefault();
        $http.post("http://localhost/myapp/scripts/login.php",
        {'username':$scope.username,'password':$scope.password})
        .success(function(data){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

            {$ionicLoading.hide();}

            if(data==="Incorrect Username or Password"){
            $scope.mainloginAlert()
    }
                else{
                if(data != "Incorrect Username or Password"){
                localStorage.setItem("customer_name",(data[0].customer_name));
                localStorage.setItem("account_number",(data[0].account_number));
                localStorage.setItem("username", $scope.username)
                $location.path = '#/tab/create_account';
                    }
                }

                }).error(function(error){
                console.error(error);
                {$ionicLoading.hide();}
                $scope.connect()
                    });

  }


}])
```

Comment: any error in browser console?

Comment: the browser don't get any errors

Comment: are you able to see value on html, ? by printing like {{username}}

Answer (score 0):

It is because localStorage.getItem("username") is returning a promise.

You have to use then to get the getItem() value.

Like this:

localStorage.getItem("username").then(function(username){  $scope.username = username })